# Running-EXE-through-web-services

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm trying to call a windows Console application in my Web Service. If I'm running it as a local service i.e in the same solution it works perfectly but if i try to call it through my Web Service hosted as IIS localServer it doesn't call it. i think it's security problem. I'm new to web service and I'm calling the application using

```
           Process.Start() function...
```

And one more thing if it's Windows Service it works great....

Any Idea???

Answer (score 3):

treat your console as a separate project.  Make sure that works first.

I've done what you've described in an asp.net web app.  I've tested it; the same code works fine in a web service.  The trick here is the `startInfo.UseShellExecute = False`

In the example, parameters are being passed to the console app which is executed at runtime.
(sorry it's in VB).

```
Dim startInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
Dim pStart As New System.Diagnostics.Process

startInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\KPIMi\Annotation Editor\Annotation_Console.exe")
startInfo.Arguments = strServerName & "-" & strPrimaryKey & "-" & txtStart.Text
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False

pStart.StartInfo = startInfo
pStart.Start()
```

`pStart.WaitForExit()` 'Your code will halt until the exe file has executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One more thing, be sure to grant the PC-NAME\ASPNET local account has access to the exe's location.

Answer (score 0):

does the IUSR_* user account have permission to execute the console application?